# Multiple definition and first defined in my C program

Tags: c, multiple-definition-error

I am reading APUE (Stevens' "[Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/)"), so there is a file "apue.h" which includes some self-definition function declared. I write a file named "wait.c" which defines functions `WAIT_CHILD`, `WAIT_PARENT` declared in "apue.h", and 14.6.c is the main function.

```
tmp/cciYhMd7.o: In function `err_ret':
14.6.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `err_ret'
/tmp/ccO4WyJS.o:wait.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

`err_ret` is just used not defined, so what's the problem??

#### wait.c

```
#include "apue.h"

static volatile sig_atomic_t sigflag;
static sigset_t newmask, oldmask, zeromask;

static void
sig_usr(int signo)
{
    sigflag = 1;
}

void
TELL_WAIT(void)
{
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
      err_sys("signal(SIGUSR1) error");
    if(signal(SIGUSR2, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
      err_sys("signal(SIGUSR2) error");

    sigemptyset(&zeromask);
    sigemptyset(&newmask);

    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR2);

    if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
      err_sys("SIG_BLOCK error");
}

void
TELL_PARENT(pid_t pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
}

void
WAIT_PARENT(void)
{
    while(sigflag == 0)
      sigsuspend(&zeromask);
    sigflag = 0;

    if(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
      err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
}

void
TELL_CHILD(pid_t pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
}

void
WAIT_CHILD(void)
{
    while(sigflag == 0)
      sigsuspend(&zeromask);
    sigflag = 0;

    if(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
      err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");
}
```

The code above is my "wait.c" source file. I just use `err_sys`. Below is the linking command line and the linker error messages I'm getting:

```
$ gcc -o a.out wait.c 14.6.c
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `err_ret':
14.6.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `err_ret'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `err_sys':
14.6.c:(.text+0x38): multiple definition of `err_sys'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x38): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `err_exit':
14.6.c:(.text+0x76): multiple definition of `err_exit'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x76): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `err_dump':
14.6.c:(.text+0xaf): multiple definition of `err_dump'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0xaf): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `err_msg':
14.6.c:(.text+0xe6): multiple definition of `err_msg'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0xe6): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `err_quit':
14.6.c:(.text+0x116): multiple definition of `err_quit'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x116): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `TELL_WAIT':
14.6.c:(.text+0x5fe): multiple definition of `TELL_WAIT'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x272): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `TELL_CHILD':
14.6.c:(.text+0x72e): multiple definition of `TELL_CHILD'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x3a2): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `WAIT_PARENT':
14.6.c:(.text+0x6d8): multiple definition of `WAIT_PARENT'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x34c): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `TELL_PARENT':
14.6.c:(.text+0x6bd): multiple definition of `TELL_PARENT'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x331): first defined here
/tmp/ccZ5F3Pn.o: In function `WAIT_CHILD':
14.6.c:(.text+0x749): multiple definition of `WAIT_CHILD'
/tmp/cc5EXGbf.o:wait.c:(.text+0x3bd): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you show us both your declaration and definition part?

Comment: the problem is the function `err_ret` which is existed in other source file, I just use it in my `wait.c` source file.Help me!

Comment: OK. But show us how are you using it?

Comment: Please see my statement , thank you first.

Comment: How about showing us *all* of your code for this program?

Comment: Have you modified `apue.h` at all?  If so, how?  If the code you show as `wait.c` is exactly what you're compiling and you've not changed `apue.h`, then you can't get the result you show.  So, something is astray; something is not as you are claiming, whether you realize what you've done or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source from the APUE book's web site has these three declarations (amongst many others) in `apue.h`:

```
void    err_ret(const char *, ...);

void    WAIT_PARENT(void);
void    WAIT_CHILD(void);
```

Judging from the error message from your compiler, not only is `err_ret()` defined, it is in fact defined twice, once in your source file `wait.c` and once in your source file `14.6.c`.  You will need to decide which (if either) of those definitions is correct, and remove the other, or decide that you can't use the code in `wait.c` with your program in `14.6.c`.  It might be better still to put `err_ret()` and friends into their own source file.  In the source, the `err_*()` functions are in `lib/error.c`.

---

> I didn't redefine the functions `err_*()`, so I think I use the `lib/error.c` source file. And in `apue.h` there's:
>
> ```
> #ifndef _APUE_H
> #define _APUE_H
> ```
>
> so I think it won't defined twice.

If your TU (translation unit) does `#include "lib/error.c"`, then your TU is defining the functions. The C compiler sees the source code containing your source plus the headers you include plus (hypothetically) the code in `lib/error.c`. You simply shouldn't be including that source file; you should compile it separately and link the object file into your program. The `apue.h` header declares the `err_*()` functions so you can use them in your code. You are expected to compile `lib/error.c` separately and link it with your `wait.o` and `14.6.o` files.

It is crucial to understand the difference between defining a variable or function (actually allocating the storage for it) and declaring a variable or function (telling the compiler that the function or variable exists, but that it is not defined here — as in 'this declaration does not define it', even if the next line in the source file does define it).  Headers should provide declarations and should not provide definitions (most of the time — it's a good enough rule for now, until you know enough to know when and how to break the rule).

---

> But what I do is just `#include "apue.h"` when I write my source file. I don't quite understand how to separately compile `lib/error.c`.

So, it sounds like you need three source files in your compile and link line:

```
gcc -o 14.6 14.6.c wait.c lib/error.c
```

Or you might do it in separate operations:

```
gcc -c 14.6.c
gcc -c wait.c
gcc -c lib/error.c -o error.o
gcc -o 14.6 14.6.o wait.o error.o
```

You might need extra compiler flags (`-I` or `-D` options for example), or extra libraries and linker options (`-llib` and `-L /directory/lib` options, for example).

If your source files 14.6.c and wait.c contain `#include "apue.h"` and do not include other source files (so no `#include "lib/error.c"` or anything similar — and `14.6.c` does not include your `wait.c` nor vice versa), then you should not run into problems.

However, you are running into problems, and we can't see your source or your linking command, which means we have to try and *guess* what you've done wrong.  We can devise all sorts of outlandish examples of what you might be doing, but we're most likely to be wrong.

So, keeping the code to a minimum, show us which files you are compiling and how you are compiling them.

Comment: In fact, I didn't redefinition the functions `err_*()`, so I think I use the `lib/error.c` source file. And in `aoue.h` `#ifndef _APUE_H
#define _APUE_H
`, so I think it won't defined twice.

Comment: If your TU (translation unit) does `#include "lib/error.c"`, then your TU is defining the functions.  The C compiler sees the source code containing your source plus the headers you include plus (hypothetically) the code in `lib/error.c`.  You simply shouldn't be including that source file; you should compile it separately and link the object file into your program.  The `apue.h` declares the `err_*()` functions so you can use them in your code.  You are expected to compile `lib/error.c` separately and link it with your `wait.o` and `14.6.o` files.

Comment: But what I do is just `#include "apue.h"` when i write my source file, I don't quite understand how to separately compile `lib/error.c`.

Comment: I want complie the `apue.h` again.

Comment: You don't really 'compile' `apue.h`; you compile with it.  C code files include `apue.h` to get the declarations, which allows the code to use the functions.  But you also have to provide definitions for the functions, and for that, you compile the source files that contain the functions.

Comment: Still the problem , I really have no idea. In makefile , `a.out:wait.c 14.6.c
 gcc -o a.out wait.c 14.6.c
`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do it, in my makefile `a.out:wait.c 14.6.c 
 gcc -o a.out wait.c 14.6.c /home/lee/program/apue/apue.2e/lib/error.c`.

Comment: But it seems wrong if I put `apue.h` header file in my current directory, instand should be in `/usr/include`, why?

Comment: Don't go messing around with `/usr/include`; it is for the system headers.  `apue.h` is 'your' header, not a system header.  Depending on where the APUE software is, you can add `-I/path/to/apue/include` to the compiler command lines to get the compiler to read `apue.h` from `/path/to/apue/include/apue.h`.  Alternatively, it belongs in your current directory until you do decide to install it.  If you decide to install it, it would be better to install it in `/usr/local/include` than `/usr/include`; the local directory is for locally added software.

Comment: I thought if i add `#include "apue.h"` in my current path, I don't need to add `-I /path/to/apue/include`.

Comment: If it is in the current directory, you don't need a `-I`; if it is somewhere else (such as `./include`), then you need an appropriate `-I` option (`-I./include` or `-I/path/to/apue/include`; either works).

Answer (score 2):

do not define functions or variables in header files.  declare them in header files, define them in .c source files.

you need to create a separate source file for the definitions and compile it separately.

also, be aware of the difference between *declaration* of global variables and *deifnition*.  If you need to declare a variable that is used by multiple .c files, you must say:

```
extern int err__ret;
```

to *declare* the variable (as an external variable) in your header file, then add:

```
int err_ret;
```

to one .c file, to *define* it.

Note also, any .c file that defines a variable or function should also include the .h file that declares it.  This will cause the compiler to produce an error if there are any discrepancies between the declaration and the definition.

Comment: yeah, I don't define a function in my header files, so I don't know what's the problem!

Comment: In "apue.h" , there are many function declarations such as `err_ret, WAIT_CHILD`, in fact `err_ret` is written  by someone else, I finish `WAIT_CHILD` in my "wait.c" source file.

Answer (score 1):

please show wait.h's entry of err_ret(), you can obscure other lines if you want. No one is asking you to compromise your NDA :)(pun intended). also have you declared err_ret() again in wait.c? if you have then it won't compile.(i'm guessing that's where the problem lies)

do preprocessing first to find multiple definitions like below:

```
$gcc -E wait.c | grep -n 'err_ret'
$gcc -E 14.6.c | grep -n 'err_ret'
```

look through the output and line numbers to find out where exactly the functions are declared and defined.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what's your meaning. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem when I compiling my `sigsetjmp.c`. Finally I find the reason is that I had `#include "error.c"` in my `apue.h`, which result in when compiling multiple c files, each file include `apue.h`, and then include `error.c`, lead to the multiple definition of the err_ret error.

Here's my suggestion:

1. Don't include any function definition c file in head file (the `apue.h`).
2. Required other c file in gcc command line or Makefile is OK.

   eg: `gcc sigsetjmp.c pr_mask.c error.c`

Hope this help.